# Php, reload page after loop

Tags: php, delete-file

I have a page which lists all the files in a server folder with a checkbox each. It works fine except the last 3 lines of code where I want it to reload the whole page. In the example below it throws it into an endless refresh. If I move the `echo` up into the `if` statement it works but only deletes one of the checked list items. I need it to delete all checked items and then reload the page. Please assist.

```
<form id="delete" action="" method="POST">
<?php
    $files = array();
    $dir = opendir('.');
    while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "download-ui.php") and ($file != "delete.php") and ($file != "error_log") and ($file != "favicon.ico")) {
            $files[] = $file; 
       }   
    }

natcasesort($files);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<li class="browse-file">
        <div class="select-all-col"><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$file.'"/>
            <a href="download-ui.php?name='.$folderName."/".$file.'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$file.'</a>
        </div>
        <br />
    </li>';
    }

?>

<button type="submit" form="delete" value="Submit">Delete File/s</button>
</form></div>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
}      
  foreach ($_POST['select'] as $file) {

    if(file_exists($file)) {
      unlink($file); 
     }
     elseif(is_dir($file)) {
           rmdir($file);
     }
  }
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$location.'">';
exit;
?>
```

Comment: you have closed if() before foreach only. check that

Comment: Put all the processing code at the top of the page before it renders to the page. Then you shouldn't need to refresh....unless you have some special purpose to refresh like that...??

Comment: @Rasclatt I need it to refresh so it shows the list again, without the items deleted, so they can either choose more items to delete or download the files that are left. I'll move the code and see what happens

Comment: Well, when you move it to the top, it deletes whatever you need then loads what's remaining. You shouldn't need the refresh or exit line

Comment: And your `if($_POST['Submit']` brackets don't look like they are properly wrapping

Comment: wow, that simple... could swear I had it at the top before... but swearings not allowed, put it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: as @Rasclatt said... Normally you would do whatever you have to dop and then show the new state of the things.

if you need it this way you could use a `header("Location:.. )` once instead of continuously refreshing the page every 0 seconds (assuming this works out of `<head>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the processing code at the top of the page before it renders to the page. Then you shouldn't need to refresh. It will process your deletes then load the rest of the page based on the remaining.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    foreach ($_POST['select'] as $file) {
        if(file_exists($file))
            unlink($file); 
        elseif(is_dir($file))
            rmdir($file);
    }
}

$files = array();
$dir = opendir('.');
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "download-ui.php") and ($file != "delete.php") and ($file != "error_log") and ($file != "favicon.ico")) {
            $files[] = $file; 
    }   
}

natcasesort($files);
?>
<form id="delete" action="" method="POST">
<?php
foreach ($files as $file) {
echo '<li class="browse-file">
        <div class="select-all-col"><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$file.'"/>
        <a href="download-ui.php?name='.$folderName."/".$file.'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$file.'</a></div>
        <br />
    </li>';
    }
?>
<button type="submit" form="delete" value="Submit">Delete File/s</button>
</form></div>
```